# rails - InvalidAuthenticityToken for json/xml requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, restful-authentication

For some reason I'm getting an InvalidAuthenticityToken when making post requests to my application when using json or xml. My understanding is that rails should require an authenticity token only for html or js requests, and thus I shouldn't be encountering this error.  The only solution I've found thus far is disabling protect_from_forgery for any action I'd like to access through the API, but this isn't ideal for obvious reasons.  Thoughts?

```
    def create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json{
            render :json => Object.create(:user => @current_user, :foo => params[:foo], :bar => params[:bar])
        }
        format.xml{
            render :xml => Object.create(:user => @current_user, :foo => params[:foo], :bar => params[:bar])
        }
    end
end
```

and this is what I get in the logs whenever I pass a request to the action:

```
 Processing FooController#create to json (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-08-07 11:52:33) [POST]
 Parameters: {"foo"=>"1", "api_key"=>"44a895ca30e95a3206f961fcd56011d364dff78e", "bar"=>"202"}

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:242:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:242:in `run'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/runner.rb:174:in `send'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/runner.rb:174:in `run_command'
  thin (1.2.2) lib/thin/runner.rb:140:in `run!'
  thin (1.2.2) bin/thin:6
  /opt/local/bin/thin:19:in `load'
  /opt/local/bin/thin:19
```

Answer (score 31):

With `protect_from_forgery` enabled, Rails requires an authenticity token for any non-GET requests. Rails will automatically include the authenticity token in forms created with the form helpers or links created with the AJAX helpers--so in normal cases, you won't have to think about it.

If you're not using the built-in Rails form or AJAX helpers (maybe you're doing unobstrusive JS or using a JS MVC framework), you'll have to set the token yourself on the client side and send it along with your data when submitting a POST request. You'd put a line like this in the `<head>` of your layout:

```
<%= javascript_tag "window._token = '#{form_authenticity_token}'" %>
```

Then your AJAX function would post the token with your other data (example with jQuery):

```
$.post(url, {
    id: theId,
    authenticity_token: window._token
});
```

Comment: Optimate should accept this answer. By the way, if you use `$.ajax` you need to put the authenticity token in the data field like this: `$.ajax( { data: { authenticity_token: window._token } } )`

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar situation and the problem was that I was not sending through the right content type headers - I was requesting `text/json` and I should have been requesting `application/json`.

I used `curl` the following to test my application (modify as necessary):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"person": {"last_name": "Lambie","first_name": "Matthew"}}' -X POST http://localhost:3000/people.json -i
```

Or you can save the JSON to a local file and call `curl` like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -d @person.json -X POST http://localhost:3000/people.json -i
```

When I changed the content type headers to the right `application/json` all my troubles went away and I no longer needed to disable forgery protection.

Comment: this doesn't really work for web applications though. Browsers can't run curl. =(

Comment: The point was that I debugged the issue with curl and found that it was important to send the right Content-Type header.

Answer (score 3):

Adding up to andymism's answer you can use this to apply the default inclusion of the TOKEN in every POST request:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    if ( settings.type == 'POST' ||  settings.type == 'post') {
        settings.data = (settings.data ? settings.data + "&" : "")
            + "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent( window._token );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Rails 4.2, we have another way is to avoid verify_authenticity_token using skip_before_filter in your Rails App:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:action1, :action2]
```

This will let curl to do its job.

Ruby on Rails 4.2 Release Notes: https://guiarails.com.br/4_2_release_notes.html

Comment: This adds a security issue. `verify_authenticity_token` runs for a reason.

Comment: Yes! It is.Don't do this! 
But is a valid answer! The best approach is in @andrewle answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1627825/757850

Answer (score 3):

As long as the JavaScript lives on the website served by Rails (for example: a JS snippet; or React app managed via webpacker) you can use the the value in `csrf_meta_tags` included in `application.html.erb` by default.

In `application.html.erb`:

```rb
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    ...
```

Therefore in the HTML of your website:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="XZY">
```

Grab the token from the `content` property and use it in the request:

```js
const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content

const response = await fetch("/entities/1", {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ authenticity_token: token, entity: { name: "new name" } })
});
```

This is similar to @andrewle's answer but there's no need for an additional token.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Fernando's answer, if your controller responds to both json and html, you can use:

```
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
```

Comment: Is this not a security risk?

Comment: Yes it is. Don't do this.