# How to turn off rails protect_from_forgery filter only for json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, rest, protect-from-forgery

I have web site built with Rails3 and now I want to implement json API for mobile client access. However, sending json post request from the client because of the protect_from_forgery filter.  Because the client will not retrieve any data from the server, there is no way that the client can receive auth_token so I would like to turn off the protect_from_forgery option only for json requests (I thought rails3 does this in default but apparently it does not).

I know similar topic is discussed at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245618/rails-invalidauthenticitytoken-for-json-xml-requests) but in that case, he receives auth_token before sending post request.

So my question is turning off the protect_from_forgery only for json is good way of doing this? If yes, how to do so? If no, what is the alternative?

FYI, I use following ajax request

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',  
             url: "http://www.example.com/login.json",  
             data: { 'email': emailVal, 'password': passwordVal },  
             success: onSuccess,  
             error: onError,  
             dataType: "json"  
});
```

and I get ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

By the way, following curl command works though...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -c cookies.txt -d '{"email": emailVal, "password": passwordVal}' -X POST http://www.example.com/login.json -i
```

Answer (score 18):

You can just skip the authenticity token check if its a json request

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this makes it vulnerable to csrf.

Comment: Use `skip_before_action` on Rails 5+.

Answer (score 7):

Add the code below to your `./app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```ruby
protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the CSRF check you can pass the authenticity_token field in your forms, eg:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v2.0.0/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods/protect_from_forgery

Comment: this might not be possible, if the UI is being built in a different project entirely