# Rails/Devise - Creating new users via json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to do a new user signup via JSON but I get an invalid authenticity token error.

I would like to not turn the forgery check for all controller. Any suggestions on how to override the registrationcontroller to do this?

Here is my code:

```
class Api::MobileRegistrationsController  < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Whitney::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :apps
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api do
    resources :tokens, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    resources :MobileRegistrations, :only => [:create] 
  end
```

I get an error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Api::MobileRegistrationsController
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't encourage you in this way, because your app will be vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

A good resource to understand CSRF : [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941594/1089771)

You should rather include the `authenticity_token` in your POST request. This is discussed in some questions on SO, like there (read all the answers) : [rails - InvalidAuthenticityToken for json/xml requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1245618/1089771)

The idea :

1. Retrieve the token with `<%= form_authenticity_token %>`
2. Add a `authenticity_token` POST param to your request with the token.

If you pass the param by URI, don't forget to encoded the token value :

```
url += "&authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent( <%= form_authenticity_token %> );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could buil your own controller that does not derive from a devise controller.

```
def UserSignupApiController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json
  def create
    @user = User.create(params[user])
    respond_with(@user)
  end
end
```

I think you get the idea. You just instantiate your User just like you would do in `Rails console`. **I do not recommend this kind of practice though**

Answer (score 0):

For your error

> Routing Error uninitialized constant
>   Api::MobileRegistrationsController

it indicates your controller is not in the correct folder. 
Because you are using

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :tokens, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    resources :MobileRegistrations, :only => [:create] 
  end
```

You need to put your MobileRegistrations into controllers/api folder. or you can use

```
scope "/api" do
  resources :MobileRegistrations, :only => [:create] 
end
```